# How to only expand one div out of a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map through an API and make each of its objects have expandable data. However, when I expand a div for one object, instead of only expanding that particular div it expands all of my objects. How do i made it so that it only expands that one object data?
Here is my code:

```
    export default function StudentsList({ students }) {
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(true);


  const handleCollapse = () => {
    setIsCollapsed((prev) => !prev);
  };


  return (
    <div className={studentsBox}>

      {students.map((student) => (
          <div className={card} key={student.id}>
             <div
                className={plus}
                onClick={handleCollapse}
                
              >
                {isCollapsed ? '+' : '-'}
              </div>
                
                <div className={isCollapsed ? collapse : ''}>
                  <p>Test 1: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[0]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 2: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[1]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 3: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[2]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 4: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[3]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 5: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[4]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 6: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[5]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 7: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[6]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 8: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[7]}%</p>
                </div>

              </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      );
   }
```

Comment: You have a single collapsed state but multiple things you’re trying to control. If you want only one expanded section you need to track which is expanded. If multiple you need a state-per-section.

Comment: something like this: change the state from const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(true); to
{student.id,collapsed} and when you set setCollapsed({...collapsed,...{id:studern.id,collapsed:true}) and check isCollapsed[studtentid].collapsed

Comment: You could introduce one more level of component structure to this.  your StudentsList would create one StudentGrades component for each student.  Is it this new StudentGrades component that will have the isCollapsed state (to show/hide the grades for that student), not the StudentsList itself.

Comment: @Oleg I tried this and ended up in a weird infinite loop!

Comment: @Wyck how would I go about doing this? I tried thinking of way I could pass through the id and such but I'm also stuck on how to save the student ID without adding another onClick

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
 export default function StudentsList({ students }) {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(null);


  const handleCollapse = (id) => {
    setCollapsed(prev => prev === id? null : id);
  };


  return (
    <div className={studentsBox}>

      {students.map((student) => (
          <div className={card} key={student.id}>
             <div
                className={plus}
                onClick={() => handleCollapse(student.id)}
                onMouseMove={() => setId(`${student.id}`)}
              >
                {collapsed === student.id ? '+' : '-'}
              </div>
                
                <div className={collapsed === student.id ? collapse : ''}>
                  <p>Test 1: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[0]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 2: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[1]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 3: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[2]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 4: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[3]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 5: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[4]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 6: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[5]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 7: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[6]}%</p>
                  <p>Test 8: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[7]}%</p>
                </div>

              </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      );
   }
```

Comment: did not work : (

Answer (score 0):

First you declare the selectedId

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
```

Then set onClick to setSelectedId

```
onClick={()=>setSelectedId(student.id)}
```

This way you can change the className base on the selectedId

```
<div className={student.id !== selectedId ? collapse : ''}>
  <p>Test 1: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[0]}%</p>
  <p>Test 2: &nbsp;&nbsp; {student.grades[1]}%</p>
....
</div>
```

Comment: So I wouldn't even need the isCollapsed at all you think??

Comment: That's right. As you map through your student entries, it will check the student.id against the selectedId state and expand the card if its id matches.

If you wish, you can also expand the onClick function that will toggle show/hide the card, i.e. when the first time the card is clicked, it will expand. Second click on the expanded card will hide it.

    onClick={()=> selectedId === student.id ? setSelectedId(null) : setSelectedId(student.id) }

Comment: Does this solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of React is to make use of lots of components.  Use additional components to add some structure to your presentation of your data.

- `StudentList` (shows a list of...)

  - `Student` (which, in turn, shows a list of...)

    - `StudentGrade`

Each student can easily be collapsed independently from the list of students.

```js
function StudentGrade({ grade, index }) {
  return <p>Test {index}: &nbsp;&nbsp; {grade}</p>
}

function Student({ student }) {
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = React.useState(true);

  const handleCollapse = () => {
    setIsCollapsed((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={handleCollapse}>
        {isCollapsed ? '-' : '+'}
        <span>{student.name}</span>
      </div>
      {!isCollapsed?null:(
        <div>
          {student.grades.map((grade, index) => (
            <StudentGrade key={index} grade={grade} index={index}/>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

function StudentsList({ students }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {students.map((student) => (
        <Student key={student.id} student={student} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const students = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Ann', grades: ['A', 'B'] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bob', grades: ['B', 'C'] },
  { id: 3, name: 'Charlie', grades: ['C', 'D'] },
]
ReactDOM.render(<StudentsList students={students} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</script>
<div id="root"></div>
```